# Retrieve data from query into one text line separates with with commas

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to retrieve a result into one text line separates with commas

```
SELECT pages_id
FROM pages
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login = 'test1');
```

I want a result like this

```
14, 15, 16, 17
```

in one line

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle database maybe this will help:

```
select listagg(Page_id, ',' ) within group (order by Page_id) 
from pages;
```

Demo:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=639c507f1b2dfe53b860c8a92d4e5e41

Comment: Thanks, I use sqlite. function group_concat helped me :)

Comment: If this helped you to get to your answer you can mark my answer as helpful and also you can write here how did you resolved your problem(in a seperated answer), because someone else will maybe need that solution